# 403 Forbidden. The request signature we calculated does not match signature you provided. Check your key and signing method from Android to Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3

I am trying to call get api using an AWS signing method but not able to get the response.
Below is my code.

```
val secretkey = "E+t5/nDf6/NKNJBjbsdjv"
val accesskey = "DJKSBDKSBNKFGNBFG"
val credentials: AWSCredentials = BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey)
val API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME = "s3"
val requestAws: Request<*> = DefaultRequest<Any?>(API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME)

val uri = URI.create("https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/..../../sample")
requestAws.endpoint = uri

requestAws.resourcePath = "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/..../../sample"
requestAws.httpMethod = HttpMethodName.GET

val signer = AWS4Signer() signer . setServiceName (API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME)
signer.setRegionName("us-west-2")
signer.sign(requestAws, credentials)
val headers = requestAws.headers

val key: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
val value: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

for ((key1, value1) in headers)
{
    key.add(key1) value . add (value1)
}

val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
val request: okhttp3.Request = okhttp3.Request.Builder()
        .url("https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/..../../sample")
        .addHeader(key[0], value[0])
        .addHeader(key[1], value[1])
        .addHeader(key[2], value[2])
        .addHeader("X-Amz-Content-Sha256", 
         "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855")
        .build()

val response: okhttp3.Response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()
Log.i("LOG", response.body.toString())
```

Not able to figure out, what I am doing mistake.
Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an Android app written in Kotlin and invokes AWS Services, use the **AWS SDK for Kotlin**.

This SDK has strongly typed Service Clients that you can use in an Android Studio project that lets you invoke a given service. (as opposed to using okhttp3.Request, etc)

For example, here is Kotlin code that invoke SNS using a Strongly typed service client named **SnsClient**.

```
    // Get all subscriptions.
     fun getSubs(view: View) = runBlocking {

        val subList = mutableListOf<String>()
        val snsClient: SnsClient = getClient()
        try {

            val request = ListSubscriptionsByTopicRequest {
                topicArn = topicArnVal
            }
            val response = snsClient.listSubscriptionsByTopic(request)
            response.subscriptions?.forEach { sub ->
                subList.add(sub.endpoint.toString())
            }

            val listString = java.lang.String.join(", ", subList)
            showToast(listString)

       } catch (e: SnsException) {
            println(e.message)
            snsClient.close()
        }
       }

 fun getClient() : SnsClient{

        val staticCredentials = StaticCredentialsProvider {
            accessKeyId = "<Enter key>"
            secretAccessKey = "<Enter key>"
        }

        val snsClient = SnsClient{
            region = "us-west-2"
            credentialsProvider = staticCredentials
        }

        return snsClient
    }
```

TO learn how to use the AWS SDK for Kotlin, see

[AWS SDK for Kotlin Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html)